# Change display name of Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, combobox, grails-domain-class

I have a one-to-one relationship, and have a combobox for selecting the other one. How do I change the display name of the combo box?

Here's a screenshot of the combo box, to make myself clear:
[image: Screenshot of cmb box]

I'm new to grails, and are attempting to create a simple data-driven app for in house use.

Edit: My toString():

```
  def toString = { "${naam} [${gemeente}]" }
```

Comment: not a direct answer, but you should take a look at http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails ; it has the basic examples that may helps. Note that the books is not very updated now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the `toString` method of said domain class.

```
String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work for me. Could you provide a sample toString? Maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: @Yvan: Sure, give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

The sig needs to be `String toString() { ... }` (you are returning a def and it is a closure, not a method)

Answer (score 0):

In grails, the select tag also has an optional attribute named "optionValue" that will allow you to define a bean field/property to display.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 3, the following works:

```
String toString() {
  return "${name}"
}
```

in your example, this would be:

```
String toString() {
  return "${naam} [${gemeente}]"
}
```

cheers!